# Logistic model selection on large data

Tags: logistic, modeling, large-data

I have a large dataset (750k rows). I have a-priorly selected 25 clinically meaningful variables for model building. I would have used likelihood ratio to build my model if not for my large dataset. Due to the large power, my likelihood ratio tests would be always be significant. Any advice on how I should proceed with model building?

Update: I started out with 19 variables. 2 removed due to multicollinearity.

Comment: What is the clinical purpose of your analysis? Why do you want to select models? Why not use all your predictor variables?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at [Regression Modeling Strategies](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RmS)?

Comment: @mdewey The purpose of the analysis is to understand the data and make inference on the characteristic of people with the event. If I use all of the predictors, may I know how do I tell that I am overfitting the model and if the variable is important?

Comment: @StasK No, I haven't. Any suggesting where I should start if I am interested in finding out more about modelling using big data?

Comment: have you looked at Variable importance tools like Boruta?  What about principal components for dimensionality reduction?

Answer (score 2):

Use a method of model selection that matches what you want to do with the model. There's no such thing as the single best model for a dataset because different models are better for different purposes. So if you want to predict scores with your model, estimate the predictive accuracies of the candidate models and use the seemingly most accurate one. Or if you want to test a scientific theory, each of which corresponds to a different model, then compare the fits of the models. Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kodiologist. So does it make sense to used pseudo R square (without using p value of course) if I would to understand the data better rather than to predict? If my aim to predict, then I should use AUC?

Comment: @tatami You're welcome. I'm not sure what specifically you mean by "understand the data", or what notion of pseudo R-square you mean. AUC isn't a measure of predictive accuracy. If you want to estimate predictive accuracy, try something like collecting predictions from tenfold cross-validation and then comparing actual to predicted outcomes with a [scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule).

Comment: I meant inferring characteristic of the event population after controlling for possible confounds. I have placed all of the variables in the model and am currently using McFadden R square to decide if the any variable should be dropped. Is the purpose of using tenfold cross-validation is to deal with large power?

Comment: @tatami "I meant inferring characteristic of the event population" — Okay, but what characteristic? "Is the purpose of using tenfold cross-validation is to deal with large power?" — No, high power isn't something to "deal with" anyway because more power is always better. The purpose of [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_\(statistics\)) is to separate training from testing.